# Can I set the dialog title of a Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker()

Tags: uwp

I am learning about the UWP pickers here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers

However I can't find any information about if I can set the dialog title or show any message. I want to tell the user WHAT to pick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vignesh mentioned, I don't believe there is a way to set a dialog title.

Strangely though, you can change the content of the **Commit** Button with the following, should it be of any use.

`picker.CommitButtonText = "TEST";`

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am going to do. At least I can convey a little bit of information to the user with that.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a possible way to change the dialog title. Since The **UWP** platform runs applications in an **AppContainer/Sandboxed** environment you will not have much control over the file dialog window.

If you want to restrict user to pick only certain types of files you can always use `FileTypeFilter` to restrict the user to choose only certain files.